# How to restrict slash command to anyone who has one of two positions on a discord server?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm developing a discord bot in Discord.js V14 and I'm working on a command called "claimticket". The problem I'm having is that I'm not being able to restrict the command to anyone who has one of the two roles that I indicate in the command.

If possible, **I would like help to restrict the claimticket command to only be used by members who have at least 1 of two roles!** Below I send the command code in full.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("../../config.json")
const StaffRolesPermitted = [`${config["ID-role"].staff}`, `${config["ID-role"]["trial-helper"]}`];

module.exports = {
    name: "claimticket",
    description: "claim a ticket",

    run: async (client, interaction) => {
        
        const member = interaction.user;
        const StaffRolesPermitted = member.roles.cache.some(role => StaffRolesPermitted.includes(role.id));

        if (!StaffRolesPermitted) {
            return interaction.reply({ content: "You do not have permission to use this command!", ephemeral: true });
        } else {

            let embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor("Green")
            .setFooter({ text: `${config.servidor.footer}`, iconURL: `${config.servidor.logo}`})
            .setDescription(`**This Ticket will be serviced by ${interaction.user}!**`)

            await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but i would try this maybe :

```js
// specify which roles are allowed
const requiredRoles = ['admin', 'moderator'];

// get user who typed the command
const member = message.member


// check if the user has one role inside the array of requiredRoles
const hasRequiredRole = requiredRoles.some((roleName) =>
    member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === roleName)
)


// your business code :D
if(hasRequiredRole){
    // do your command function
} else {
    // no permission
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Docs https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/collection/main/Collection:Class#hasAny

```
// Role IDs
const roles = ["123", "456", "789"]

if (<GuildMember>.roles.cache.hasAny(...roles)) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).